# How to add citations and references in patent document?

Tags: reference, cited

I'm drafting a provisional patent for my own invention and wish to cite a case study from an online source. First of all, should I even mention a case study and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Does the online source cite a published primary source?

Comment: Why are you citing it?

Comment: @EricS No, it doesn't. The online source is like a news article.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Not sure why I'm citing but I thought maybe to give better context and to offer an example?

Comment: Provisional applications do not have strict formality requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to answer this sort of question because I am not a lawyer. Hopefully if I'm off base someone will provide enough feedback or post a better answer.

A provisional application (not a provisional patent) just establishes a priority date. A provisional application never becomes a patent. For that you need to file a non-provisional application. In all likelihood, the provisional application will never even get read by an examiner. Thus, I would avoid loading up your provisional with anything other than a description of the invention itself. I'm having trouble understanding what value citing a web based case study provides. If it describes you invention then it is prior art. If it doesn't then why cite it?

As always, I highly recommend consulting with an actual patent attorney or agent.